# delete request with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, message-queue, sidekiq

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Sidekiq. I want to set this delete request to be done in Sidekiq queue and I don't know how to send it to the perform method, I am sending the Book model to the perform method

**My controller Action code**

```
def destroy
    BaseWorkerJob.perform_async(Book)
end
```

**My BaseWorkerJob class code**

```
class BaseWorkerJob
   include Sidekiq::Job
   sidekiq_options retry:0

   def perform(book)
   # Do something
     book.find(params[:id]).destroy!
     sleep 15
   end
end
```

**SideKiq Error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVxJl.png)

ruby 3.1.2 
Rails 7.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the model name and object id to the worker

```
def destroy
  BaseWorkerJob.perform_async(Book.to_s, params[:id])
end
```

```
class BaseWorkerJob
  include Sidekiq::Job
  sidekiq_options retry: 0

  def perform(klass_name, object_id)
    klass_name.constantize.find(object_id).destroy!
  end
end
```

Try it out!

Comment: can you pls refer to me a good reference for how to use SideKiq with restful APIs?
as I want to try this also in the Post Request but still have no idea how to do it.
@rajdeep-singh